# Problema con phpMyAdmin, error de composer detected issues

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Estoy teniendo el siguiente problema con phpMyAdmin luego de haber desintalado XAMPP y haberlo vuelto a instalar; y es lo siguiente:

me aparece el error que dice:

```
Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require the following PHP extensions to be installed: mysqli, openssl
```

Comment: sistema operativo? versión de php?

Comment: Mi sistema operativo es Windows 8.1 y la versión de PHP es 8.0.3

Comment: fijate si están activados en el panel de control del xampp, si ahí no aparece buscar en `\xampp\php\php.ini` a ver si ahí están comentadas ( un `;` al inicio de línea ) las líneas que cargan extensiones por ejemplo `extension=mysqli`

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso era modificar el php.ini y sacarle el **;** en la línea a

```
extension=mysqli
```

Comment: Correcto , Esta seria la respuesta